# Cannot find ruby.h file in system

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

```
Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200330-8267-hpu1jf.rb extconf.rb
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/rbconfig.rb:215: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 in PATH, mode 040777
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.12.2/gem_make.out
```

I am trying to download CocoaPods and this error is generatedThe system wasn't able to find ruby.h file but when I digged a little deep, I found out that there is no folder like include in the location specified(/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h). I even tried to manually add the folder but the system didn't give me permission for that even when I used sudo command.

Comment: I would strongly recommend installing your own ruby, e.g. with rbenv.

Comment: Use something like rbenv or rvm which will handle installing any required components.

Comment: As said above, don't try to install into, or change the Ruby installed by Apple; It's really there for their own purposes. Instead, use rbenv or RVM to manage your own Ruby in your home directory. rbenv is less complicated, RVM has more features; Take your pick. In either case, read their documentation, especially about installing, and don't *ever* use `sudo` unless you know exactly what you're doing.